# A delayed Consume

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

Is it possible to Consume an item in the queue with some delay?

There is a retry functionality where I can set intervals, but I need to delay the first time the item is being consumed.

**EDIT**

What I see here: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit-Quartz is what I need actually.

Something like:

```
bus.SchedulePublish(30.Seconds().FromNow, new MyMessage(someId, someValue));
```

Which will publish the message after 30 seconds.

But how can I build this solution so I can retrieve the `MassTransit.Quartz.dll`? I keep getting the error `SolutionVersion.cs could not be found.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a NuGet package for it, `MassTransit.Quartz`, which includes the assembly.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/masstransit.quartz

I'd suggest using that over building it yourself.

Also, if you're within a consumer, you can send the message back to yourself easily using extension methods on the consume context. Check the documentation for updates, but `ScheduleSend` is the method.

`SchedulePublish()` is okay, but `ScheduleSend()` to a specific endpoint is preferred if you know where the message is heading.

Comment: We are going to build a lot of Consumer methods, I actually don't want to implement the same in each Consumer. But SchedulePublish() looks good, Gonna try it out. BTW, is it MassTransit.QuartzIntegration.dll that I have to use? I can't find a MassTransit.Quartz.dll.

Comment: I directly linked the NuGet package in my response, yes I think the actual DLL is QuartzIntegration.

Comment: I added MassTransit.QuartzIntegration.dll as a reference into my project, but `SchedulePublish` isn't being recognized. can you help me with this?

Comment: SchedulePublish is in the RabbitMQ assembly.

Comment: Sorry but that didn't help me a lot. Which assembly do you mean... I downloaded the whole package from the nuget link. Which dll do I have to reference so I can use SchedulePublish? I can't find any complete example of this... It makes me disappointed.

Comment: If you need more interactive help, I'd suggest https://gitter.im/MassTransit/MassTransit